# Return value with INDEX/MATCH and a logical test

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table with unique values displayed in rows. I need to return the value the correct first login time for the day

```
     A        B         C            D
1    Session  User      Date         Time
2    1000     U1        3/6/2017     10:01
3    1234     U1        3/6/2017     12:00
```

As you can see, it's possible for one agent to log in twice for the day, and I only need **the first time**.

I figured I could use INDEX and MATCH with multiple criteria for the User and the Date, but how do I include a **logical test to check the session with the lower number** (later sessions are always with a higher session ID number)?

My formula so far looks something like this:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH("U1"&"3/6/2017",B:B&C:C,0),D:D)
```

I'm not actually using U1 and the date directly, but with cell references, so the syntax error is not a problem.

Also, I know this is an array formula, so it's confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

However, I don't know how to continue from here and say check U1 in B:B and Date in C:C, but return only D;D for the lowest Session in A:A

Comment: Please include your formula so far. And you can use `MIN()` to find the lowest value, i.e. the earliest hour! ;)

Comment: Hi there. My formula so far looks something like this: `=INDEX(A:D,MATCH("U1"&"3/6/2017",B:B&C:C,0),D:D)`. I'm not actually using U1 and the date directly, but with cell references, so the syntax error is not a problem. Also, I know this is an array formula, so it's confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. However, I don't know how to continue from here and say `check U1 in B:B and Date in C:C, but return only D;D for the lowest Session in A:A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include an extra helper column `IsFisrtLogin` with formula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,$C2,$A:$A,"<"&$A2)=0
```

Then filter out only the rows where this formula evaluates to `TRUE` and you will get only the first logins per corresponding user and day (i.e. the lowest session number).

Comment: This is perfect - I love simple solutions. Thank you, Taosique!

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` was right. If they are in time order there's no need to find a minimum anything, just find the first occurrence - which is exactly what `MATCH` does.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$3,MATCH(G2&H2,$C$2:$C$3&$D$2:$D$3,0))
```

Entered as an *array* formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

The result looks like this (see column `I`)

[image]

Comment: After all of the OP's edits, I believe he/she actually wants the time associated with the user, day and lowest session number so one more level of lookup may be necessary.

Comment: If that's the case OP could just change the `INDEX($B$2:$B$3,` to `INDEX($E$2:$E$3,`? This all assumes that the results come out in order of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/((B$1:B$99="U1")*(C$1:C$99=DATE(2017, 3, 6))*(A$1:A$99=AGGREGATE(15, 6, (A$1:A$99)/((B$1:B$99="U1")*(C$1:C$99=DATE(2017, 3, 6))), 1))), 1))
```

This retrieves the lowest numerical session number for the supplied date then uses that in a similar wrapping formula to retrieve the time associated with the session, the user and the date. Remember to format the result as time; it will be originally retrieved as a raw number.

The `"U1"` and `DATE(2017, 3, 6)` could refer to a cell(s) containing the value. For the second, third, etc match, replace the `, 1)` (the *k* of AGGREGATE's SMALL subfunction) with the appropriate ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this as an array formula (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) :

```
=INDEX(A:D,
    MATCH(
        MIN(INDEX(A:D,MATCH("U1"&"3/6/2017",B:B&C:C,0))&"U1"&"3/6/2017"
        ,D:D&B:B&C:C,0)
        ,D:D)
```

In fact it's just getting the minimum of your initial function and matching it with the user and the day, to get your desired result! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the formulas, you can create a PivotTable that automatically shows you the Session number and Time of the first login for each user each day, regardless of the order of the data:

[image: PivotTable]

1. Insert PivotTable
2. Add User, Date and Sessions to Row Labels (You can swap User and Date, but Sessions must be last)
3. Add Time to Values
4. Summarize Time by Min (Sum/Max actually have same result if Sessions are unique, because there's only 1 value per Session. Min just sounds nicer here.)
5. Change Number format of Min of Time field to Time (Right click on Field, Value Field Settings, Number Format, Time)
6. Change Report Layout to Tabular (On PivotTable Tools > Design tab)
7. Change Report Layout to Repeat all Item Labels
8. Remove Subtotals
9. Remove Grand Totals
10. Right click on Session field and select Filter > Top 10...
11. Set to: Show Bottom 1 Items by Min of Time (This causes only the first Session to be displayed for each User/Date combination based on the earliest Time)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael. Unfortunately, a pivot won't work for me, because I need to use the extracted value in another table to match it against scheduled time.